# Weird difference using match phrase/terms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Recently I've come across a very weird and frustrating problem using elasticsearch. I've indexed about 1 million documents using the NEST API. The index contains a full-text field as below:

```
{"title": {"include_in_all": false, "analyzer": "ik_max_word", "type": "string"}}
```

The data in the field are primarily Chinese and ik_max_word is a Chinese analyzer with the finest granule. The problem is:

1) Typically I'm using a match phrase query on that field, and when i query like "ABC" (I substitute the Chinese characters here), I got only 260 results. The search query is liked:

```
"match": {
            "title": {
              "type": "phrase",
              "query": "非公开",
              "analyzer": "ik_max_word"
            }
          }
```

2) While if I'm using a term query of "ABC", I got 20000+ results.

3) Moreover, if I query "ABCDE" using match phrase, I got 4000 results.

I'm very confused here. The field is an analyzed field and I think if I can get 20000+ results using the term query, then the analyzer is fine separating the characters and putting them into the inverted index. I understand that a match phrase query combines terms with the help of position info, so I think I should get at least 20000+ results here instead of only 260.

Thanks for any help on that!

---

The config of ik in elasticsearch.yml is:

```
index:
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      ik:
          alias: [ik_analyzer]
          type: org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.IkAnalyzerProvider
      ik_max_word:
          type: ik
          use_smart: false
      ik_smart:
          type: ik
          use_smart: true
index.analysis.analyzer.default.type : "ik"
```

Comment: How is the `ik_max_word` analyzer configured?

Comment: Like this in the elasticsearch.yml:

`index:
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      ik:
          alias: [ik_analyzer]
          type: org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.IkAnalyzerProvider
      ik_max_word:
          type: ik
          use_smart: false
      ik_smart:
          type: ik
          use_smart: true
index.analysis.analyzer.default.type : "ik"`

Comment: Could you update the question to include the analyzer?